# ValueListanableBuilder is not updating after deleting an item in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to delete an item from an list and it isnot updating the UI, it only updates after moving to another screen. The insert method is working and updating perfectly but the deleting is not. What am I doing wrong? I tried to notify the listeners is a bunch of ways but unsuccesfully.

bellow is my code

```
class _DialogBottomState extends State<DialogBottom> {
  final controller = InsertBoletoController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DialogBottom(
GestureDetector(
                onTap: ()  async {
                await boletosNotifier.deletarBoleto(widget.data.id).then(
                        (_) => Navigator.pop(context));
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
```

```
class BoletoListController {
  final boletosNotifier = ValueNotifier<List<BoletoModel>>(<BoletoModel>[]);
  List<BoletoModel> get boletos => boletosNotifier.value;
  set boletos(List<BoletoModel> value) => boletosNotifier.value = value;
  final BoletoDao dao = BoletoDao();
  BoletoListController(){
    getBoletos();

  }

  Future<void> getBoletos() async {
    try {
      // final instance = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      // final response = instance.getStringList('boletos') ?? [];
      boletos = await dao.getBoletoList();
    } catch (e){
      boletos = [];
    }
  }


  Future<void> deletarBoleto(String id) async {
    return await dao.deleteBoleto(id);
    boletosNotifier.notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
class _BoletoListWidgetState extends State<BoletoListWidget> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<List<BoletoModel>>(
      valueListenable: widget.controller.boletosNotifier,
      builder: (_, boletos, __) => Column(
        children: boletos.map((e) => BoletoTileWidget(data: e)).toList(),
      ),);
  }
}
```

```
class _MeusBoletosPageState extends State<MeusBoletosPage> {
  final controller = BoletoListController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: AppColors.primary,
                  height: 40,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                  child: ValueListenableBuilder<List<BoletoModel>>(
                    valueListenable: controller.boletosNotifier,
                    builder: (_, boletos, __) =>
                        AnimatedCard(
                            direction: AnimatedCardDirection.top,
                            child: BoletoInfoWidget(size: boletos.length)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24, left: 24, right: 24),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Meus boletos",
                    style: TextStyles.titleBoldHeading,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24, horizontal: 24),
              child: Divider(thickness: 1, height: 1, color: AppColors.stroke),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
              child: BoletoListWidget(
                controller: controller,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is beacuse `controller.boletosNotifier.value` does not change when deleting "brazilian tickets"

Comment: how can I change this value to update?

Comment: I found out that if I call setState(){} from HomePage iit updated but it dows not work when I call setState from the dialog. I tried passing the setState as parameter but it did'nt work either